# How to convert image into stream in JMeter?

Tags: image, jmeter, jpeg

I am trying to convert jpg image to stream in JMeter using BeanShell Pre-process. Below code is converting into byte array? How to convert to stream?

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Projects\\Experiments\\samplephotoCTS.jpg");

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
    for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
    }
    in.close();
    byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    vars.put("imageData", new String(imageData));
```

Comment: which "stream"?

Comment: I meant "Byte stream"